# Add user defined metadata to realm schema

Tags: react-native, realm-js

I started using realm react native SDK and I am wondering if I can define a user defined attribute for a given object or attribute.

With Apple Core Data there was a User Info dictionary attached to NSEntityDescription / NSPropertyDescription and I would like to know if an equivalent property exists in Realm objects.

Otherwise, can I add my own property to the realm objects ? for instance something like that :

```
export const Account = {
    name: "Account",
    myUserInfoForObject: { objectInfo1: false, objectInfo2: "xyz" }
    properties: {
        email: { type: "string", myUserInfoForProperty: { info1: true, info2: "abc" } }
    }
```

By the way, I still did not understand if "Account" must extends Realm.Object (so if it is inheritance) or if Realm only needs an object which has the "name" / "properties" to work.